# Grouping list items by comparing them with their neighbors

Tags: scala

What is the most elegant way of grouping a list of values into groups based on their neighbor values?

The wider context I have is having a list of lines, that need to be grouped into paragraphs. I want to be able to say that if the vertical difference between two lines is lower than threshold, they are in the same paragraph.

I ended up solving this problem differently, but I'm wondering about the correct solution here.

```
case class Box(y: Int)
val list = List(Box(y=1), Box(y=2), Box(y=5))

def group(list: List[Box], threshold: Int): List[List[Box]] = ???

val grouped = group(list, 2)
> List(List(Box(y=1), Box(y=2)), List(Box(y=5)))
```

I have looked at [`groupBy()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@groupBy[K](f:A=>K):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]), but that can only work with one element at a time. I have also tried an approach that involved pre-computing differences using [`sliding()`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@sliding(size:Int,step:Int):Iterator[Repr]), but then it becomes awkward to retrieve the elements from the original collection.

Comment: Can you please give an example of `f(xs) == ys` where `f` is the desired function signature, `xs` is example input, and `ys` is the desired output?

Comment: In the code block its the `group` function, it takes a list of boxes, a threshold and produces a list of lists of boxes such that boxes, whose `y`s are less than threshold apart are grouped into one list

Comment: could you please translate that into code? It's easier for me to understand the code (function signature, input and desired output) over words

Comment: Perhaps `partition` achieves what you need? `val (underThreshold, overThreshold) = boxes.partition(_.y < threshold)`. If not, your example is probably too specific to grasp the idea of what you want to achieve.

Comment: This question comes up often, and the answer is to write your own to slide and group by some predicate. I couldn't find a particular ML thread recently as a sample answer. I wonder if it's been put in a lib somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's  a one liner. Generalising types left as an exercise for the reader.

Using ints and absolute difference rather than lines and spacing to avoid clutter.

```
val zs = List(1,2,4,8,9,10,15,16)  
def closeEnough(a:Int, b:Int) = (Math.abs(b -a) <= 2)

zs.drop(1).foldLeft(List(List(zs.head)))
                      ((acc, e)=> if (closeEnough(e, acc.head.head)) 
                                      (e::acc.head)::acc.tail
                                  else
                                       List(e)::acc)
       .map(_.reverse)
       .reverse

// List(List(1, 2, 4), List(8, 9, 10), List(15, 16))
```

Or a two liner for a slight efficiency gain

```
val ys = zs.reverse
ys.drop(1).foldLeft(List(List(ys.head)))
                ((acc, e)=> if (closeEnough(e, acc.head.head)) 
                   (e::acc.head)::acc.tail
                else
                   List(e)::acc)
// List(List(1, 2, 4), List(8, 9, 10), List(15, 16))
```

Comment: `head` and `tail` are not safe (they throw exception on empty list) and their usage in functional context is discouraged. Use `headOption` and `drop(1)` instead.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of this.  However, the uses of `head` within the `foldLeft` are entirely safe, and "fixing" the ones in setting up the `foldLeft` are better fixed by doing a single test for `zs.isEmpty` first.

Comment: Although `zs.drop(1)`  does make things safe here. I'll use that. Updated, it now works on empty lists too (and alll the uses of `head` are never used on empty lists)

Comment: I agree that `head` is safe here,  but still would be more elegant (and readable) to deconstruct the list with the `::` extractor rather that using `head` and `tail` explicitly.
Also, `reverse` + `foldLeft` === `foldRight` .

Comment: Actually, I don't think it would be more elegant (in this precise case, generally I agree with you). Try it and you'll see what I mean - although if you can make it more elegant, I'll be happy to be proved wrong. And although `reverse` + `foldLeft` is indeed equivalent to `foldRight`,  I  would need to get the reversed `head` (original `last`) which would be an extra traversal of the list.