# How to check whether two Options are both defined / undefined in scala

Tags: scala

I want to check whether the "state" of two options are the same:

```
val a : Option[Double]= ??
val b : Option[Double]= ??
```

How can this be written in a nice way?

```
val sameState = (a.isDefined && b.isDefined) || (!a.isDefined && !b.isDefined)
```

So in words : If a is None and b is None it shoud return true, if a is Some and b is Some it should also return true, otherwise it should return false

My solution seems quite unscala-ish. I'm looing for something like:

```
val sameState = (a.definition == b.definition)
```

Edit : background:

I have a `Seq[Option[_]]` and want to split it into a `Seq[Seq[Option[_]]` depending on whether the "state" of consecutive elements changes as in [Grouping list items by comparing them with their neighbors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816015/grouping-list-items-by-comparing-them-with-their-neighbors)

Comment: Can you clarify with some better input and output for your problem like how the consecutive element need to change?

Comment: @PuneethReddyV I could, but this is not related to my question. I think my question is clear enough by how I impemented `sameState` so far. If a is None and b is None it shoud return true, if a is Some and b is Some it should also return true, otherwise it should return false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just `a.isDefined == b.isDefined` ?

Comment: this does not satisfy my requirement

Comment: `val sameState = (a.isDefined && b.isDefined) || (!a.isDefined && !b.isDefined)` - that's you requirement, right?
It does exactly the same

Comment: you are right, I did not see that you use `==` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer myself. There is also a `size` attribute on `Option` (being 1 for Some, 0 for None):

```
val sameState = (a.size == b.size)
```

Why this works? There is an implicit conversion from `Option[A]` to `Iterable[A]` called `option2Iterable`

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `match` over the tuple of two option you are having. Something like this

```
def isBothDefined(a : Option[Double], b : Option[Double]) = (a,b) match{
  case (Some(x), Some(y)) => "Both defined"
  case (Some(x), None) => "b is not defined"
  case (None, Some(y)) => "a is not defined"
  case _ => "nither s defined"
}
```

Output

```
isBothDefined(Option.apply(1.0), Option.empty[Double])
res3: String = b is not defined
```

Comment: I don't want to check whether x == y, just whether both are defined or both are not defined.

Comment: yes, this is more or less what I have so far, but this takes even more lines of code...