# Scala extract neighbours in a List who differ by 1 (Ints)

Tags: algorithm, scala, extract

I'm currently trying to extract neighbours in a List who differ by 1. For example if I had my List like this:

```
List(1,2,3,7,8,10,13,14)
//By extracting I want to get:
List(
    List(1,2,3),
    List(7,8),
    List(10),
    List(13,14)
    )
```

I've tried it myself by doing foldLeft, I felt like I was close but yet so far. Can anyone help me? Any suggestions? ^^
Thank you so much! :)

Comment: show how close you were ...

Comment: Obviously your question is full of irony but still. With initial value being List(List(Int)) I've tried folding it and matching values(seeing if they differ by 1). But creating new lists doesn't seem to work. Compiler throws an error. That's how close I were. I feel like it's the right approach but still I'm pretty new to functional programming.

Comment: there is no irony. Just check out this advice for future reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/37816015/5986907 which perhaps isn't quite a duplicate as this is more specific and can be optimised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `foldRight`:

```
val oldList = List(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14)

val newList = oldList.foldRight[List[List[Int]]](Nil)((a, b) => b match {
  case (bh @ bhh :: _) :: bt if (bhh - a == 1) => (a :: bh) :: bt
  case _ => (a :: Nil) :: b
})
```

So we iterate the entries backwards and either prepend to the existing head list or add a new head list depending on whether the difference is one:

```
Nil
(14, ...) => (14 :: Nil) :: Nil
(13, ...) => (13 :: 14 :: Nil) :: Nil
(10, ...) => (10 :: Nil) :: (13 :: 14 :: Nil) :: Nil
...
```

I haven't used Scala for a while so this might not be the best solution, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Consecutive integers will increment in line with the list index, thus we can subtract the index and they'll form groups of the same number

```
val li = List(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14)
val groups = li.zipWithIndex.groupBy({case (e, i) => e - i})  // group numbers
groups.values.toList.map(_.map(_._1))  // drop indices and grouping keys
```

Note: these will lose the ordering of unordered initial list. For your case, you can reorder with `.sortBy(_.head)`

Answer (score 1):

```
  //First Part: Separates the list into ordered pairs with tail - head == 1
  val ls = List(1,2,3,7,8,10,13,14)

  val lb: ListBuffer[List[Int]] = new ListBuffer[List[Int]]()

  for (List(left,right) <- ls.sorted.sliding(2)) {
    if (right - left == 1) {
      lb += List(left, right)
    }else {
      if(!lb.flatten.toList.contains(left)) lb += List(left)
    }
  }

  println(lb.toList)

  //Second Part: Merges ordered pairs (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) when y1 == y2
  val finalLb: ListBuffer[List[Int]] = new ListBuffer[List[Int]]()

  for (List(left,right) <- lb.toList.sliding(2)) {
    if(left.tail.contains(right.head)) {
      finalLb += (left ++ right).distinct
    }else{
      finalLb += right
    }
  }

  println(finalLb.toList)
```

Outputs

```
First Part: List(List(1, 2), List(2, 3), List(7, 8), List(10), List(13, 14))
Second Part: List(List(1, 2, 3), List(7, 8), List(10), List(13, 14))
```