# Dynamic sliding window in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose, I have a log file of events (page visits) with a timestamp. I'd like to group events into sessions where I consider that events belong to the same session when they are not further than `X` minutes from each other.

Currently, I ended up with this algorithm.

```
val s = List(1000, 501, 500, 10, 3, 2, 1) // timestamps
val n = 10 // time span

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

(s.head +: s).sliding(2).foldLeft(ListBuffer.empty[ListBuffer[Int]]) {
  case (acc, List(a, b)) if acc.isEmpty =>
    acc += ListBuffer(a)
    acc
  case (acc, List(a, b)) =>
    if (n >= a - b) {
      acc.last += b
      acc
    } else {
      acc += ListBuffer(b)
      acc
    }
}
```

The result

`ListBuffer(ListBuffer(1000), ListBuffer(501, 500), ListBuffer(10, 3, 2, 1))`

Is there any better/functional/efficient way to do it?

Comment: to clarify, for timespan 10, are 4, 10, 16 all in the same session even though the outer two are more than 10 apart? that is, how do you treat overlapping sessions?

Comment: this question is slight (trivial?) generalisation of this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/52018499/5986907

Comment: @JoelBerkeley `for timespan 10, are 4, 10, 16 all in the same session` yes, they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018821/5986907) by altering the condition ...

```
s.foldRight[List[List[Int]]](Nil)((a, b) => b match {
  case (bh @ bhh :: _) :: bt if (bhh + n >= a) => (a :: bh) :: bt
  case _ => (a :: Nil) :: b
})
```